# Pytest fail in Github Action but work locally

Tags: flask, pytest, github-actions

I wrote a simple pytest to test databased access endpoint and it runs fine locally, but when I trigger pytest in Github Action as part of my CI/CD it doesn't work.  Is there some sort of port I need to open or something?

This is my test:

```
def test_if_columns_match(Test_Client, Test_Table):
    response = Test_Client.get('/database/search/test_table')
    api_data = response.get_json()[0]
    api_columns = sorted(api_data.keys())
    db_columns = sorted(Test_Table.c.keys())
    assert api_columns == db_columns, 'Columns do not match'
```

With the fail message this:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________ test_if_columns_match _____________________________

Test_Client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'src.server'>>
Test_Table = Table('test_table', MetaData(), Column('id', VARCHAR(collation='utf8mb4_unicode_ci', length=255), table=<test_table>, ... Column('gender', VARCHAR(collation='utf8mb4_unicode_ci', length=45), table=<test_table>, nullable=False), schema=None)

    def test_if_columns_match(Test_Client, Test_Table):
        response = Test_Client.get('/database/search/test_table')
>       api_data = response.get_json()[0]
E       TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

tests/test_endpoints.py:31: TypeError
```

my endpoint basically just go to the database and load the table using sqlaclchemy and serialize it.  It works locally.

My database don't have any IP requirement, so any server should work.  This is my Github Action:

```
name: Python Unit Test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, dev ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Test with pytest
      id: test
      working-directory: ./
      run: |
        pytest tests -vv -rf -x > unit-test-result.log
      continue-on-error: true
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is more debugging info:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________ test_if_columns_match _____________________________

Test_Client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'src.server'>>
Test_Table = Table('test_table', MetaData(), Column('id', VARCHAR(collation='utf8mb4_unicode_ci', length=255), table=<test_table>, ... Column('gender', VARCHAR(collation='utf8mb4_unicode_ci', length=45), table=<test_table>, nullable=False), schema=None)

    def test_if_columns_match(Test_Client, Test_Table):
        response = Test_Client.get('/database/search/test_table')
>       assert response.get_data() == ""
E       assert b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>\n' == ''
E        +  where b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>\n' = <bound method Response.get_data of <WrapperTestResponse 192 bytes [400 BAD REQUEST]>>()
E        +    where <bound method Response.get_data of <WrapperTestResponse 192 bytes [400 BAD REQUEST]>> = <WrapperTestResponse 192 bytes [400 BAD REQUEST]>.get_data
```

Comment: If `response.get_json()` is returning `None`, that suggests that you're not receiving JSON data. The first step would be figuring out what you *are* receiving. You should probably start by asserting a successful response code (`assert response.status_code == 200`) to make sure the API request is succcessful.

Comment: Next, you probably want to assert the contents of `response.get_data()`.

Comment: Add an `if response:`

Comment: Hey guys, ok I added more assert and it turn to be 400, I added the detail info to the question.  Why would it give 400 when it run locally??  I am using pytest test_client

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  Turn out Flask Test Sever don't create args and param objects in the request on the server side if none is explicitly sent to it, so it was failing trying to parse that.  Fixed by adding try block around arg/param parsing code.